# Scala syntax/grammar of type system example?

Tags: scala, type-systems

I'm learning scala.

In scala syntax: https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/13-syntax-summary.html, I read about the `type system`.

```
  Type              ::=  FunctionArgTypes ‘=>’ Type
                      |  InfixType [ExistentialClause]
  FunctionArgTypes  ::= InfixType
                      | ‘(’ [ ParamType {‘,’ ParamType } ] ‘)’
  ExistentialClause ::=  ‘forSome’ ‘{’ ExistentialDcl {semi ExistentialDcl} ‘}’
  ExistentialDcl    ::=  ‘type’ TypeDcl
                      |  ‘val’ ValDcl
  InfixType         ::=  CompoundType {id [nl] CompoundType}
  CompoundType      ::=  AnnotType {‘with’ AnnotType} [Refinement]
                      |  Refinement
  AnnotType         ::=  SimpleType {Annotation}
  SimpleType        ::=  SimpleType TypeArgs
                      |  SimpleType ‘#’ id
                      |  StableId
                      |  Path ‘.’ ‘type’
                      |  ‘(’ Types ‘)’
  TypeArgs          ::=  ‘[’ Types ‘]’
  Types             ::=  Type {‘,’ Type}
  Refinement        ::=  [nl] ‘{’ RefineStat {semi RefineStat} ‘}’
  RefineStat        ::=  Dcl
                      |  ‘type’ TypeDef
                      |
  TypePat           ::=  Type

  Ascription        ::=  ‘:’ InfixType
                      |  ‘:’ Annotation {Annotation}
                      |  ‘:’ ‘_’ ‘*’
```

I can give some examples:

1. when `StableId` is `Int`, and `StableId => SimpleType => AnnotType => CompoundType => InfixType => Type`, we will get a `Type` called `Int`.
2. when `FunctionArgTypes` is `()`, `Type` is `Int`, we will get a `Type` called `()=>Int`.
3. when `Type` is `Array`, `TypeArgs` is `[Int]`, we will get `SimpleType` = `Array[Int]`, then `Type` is `Array[Int]`.

I don't understand some of the type system:

1. What's the `InfixType` ?
2. What's the `CompoundType` ?
3. What's the `Refinement` ?
4. What's the `Ascription` ?
5. When will `SimpleType` derive a `SimpleType '#' id`, and when will derive `'(' Types ')'` ?

Is there any examples for scala type system ?

Comment: You can't learn Scala by looking at the grammar, you need to follow a tutorial, look at sample code, and then try things for yourself.

Comment: @Tim, yes, But I really want to understand the grammar.

Comment: Your questions are about the semantics, not the grammar. The names of the symbols have no relevance to the grammar, they are just there to give a hint to the semantic interpretation that is going to be applied. For example, `InfixType` could just as well be `CuddlyToy` and the grammar would be unchanged.

Comment: Why you want to learn the grammar of the language? It is there for the compiler team and people wanting to write meta-tools for the language, not really for newcomers.

Comment: @jwvh just want to learn something in scala compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. For example `Op` in `Int Op String` is an infix type

   ```
   trait Op[A, B]

   type T = Int Op String
   ```
2. For example `Int with String with Boolean` is a compound type.
3. For example `{ type X }` is a type refinement in

   ```
   trait MyTrait

   type T = MyTrait { type X }
   ```
4. For example `: Int` in `1 : Int` is a type ascription.
5. For example `MyTrait#T` is a type projection

   ```
   trait MyTrait {
     type T
   }
   ```

   Type

   ```
   type T = (Int, String, Boolean)
   ```

   is a tuple type.